# CMS Made Simple FormBuilder captcha issue

Tags: content-management-system, captcha, formbuilder, cmsmadesimple

Hoping someone can help with a CMS Made Simple form builder question.  I have a site that's recently started sending out lots of spam emails through the form.  I used form builder to build the form, tried ticking the "Check here to protect your form with a "Captcha" box in Captcha settings, but when I do that, the entire head section of my page disappears, the form html doesn't load and no html after where the form should be is rendered. It basically just destroys the page.

I'm using:

CMS Made Simple 1.6 "New Caledonia", 
FormBuilder 0.5.11, 
Captcha 0.4

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version of CMSMS was released in June 2009, there has been 4.5 years of development of the core software since then. I suspect your system is trying to install the Captcha module and failing because core files are so out of date.

Consider upgrading and then adding Captcha:
http://docs.cmsmadesimple.org/upgrading/general-information